# How to set column header text for specific column in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to set column header text for specific column in Datagridview C#

Answer (score 55, accepted):

there is **HeaderText** property in Column object, you can find the column and set its HeaderText after initializing grid or do it in windows form designer via designer for DataGrid.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "First Column"; 
        //..............
    }
```

More details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx) at MSDN. More details about DataGrid are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx).

Comment: How do you accomplish the same thing without calling the cellvaluechanged event?

Comment: Well it has been some time since I used this, but I think if you do it via designer (if you know before hand what you want the column value to be) it should not bother to fire event. Or you can set some marker like `settingHeader=true;` and then check for this in `callvaluechanged` handler to skip any action.

Answer (score 54):

For info, if you are binding to a class, you can do this in your type via `DisplayNameAttribute`:

```
[DisplayName("Access key")]
public string AccessKey { get {...} set {...} }
```

Now the header-text on auto-generated columns will be "Access key".

Answer (score 7):

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText
```

or

```
grid.Columns["columnname"].HeaderText
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dg_View.Columns.Add("userid","User Id");
Dg_View.Columns[0].Width = 100;

Dg_View.Columns.Add("username", "User name");
Dg_View.Columns[0].Width = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void datagrid_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string test = this.datagrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
}
```

This code will get the `HeaderText` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with visual studio designer, you will probably have defined fields for each columns in the `YourForm.Designer.cs` file e.g.:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dataGridViewCheckBoxColumn1;    
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2;
```

If you give them useful names, you can set the `HeaderText` easily:

```
usefulNameForDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Useful Header Text";
```

Answer (score -1):

dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Your Header";

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.