# unable to change Column names when populating with list and using Auto-generate fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The default column names are item1, item2 and item3 and I'm unable to change these, I've seen a similar question on here but none of the solutions seemed to work.

```
  if (depositTotal != cartTotal & depositTotal != 0.0)
  {
      list.Add(Tuple.Create(amazonOrderID, depositTotal, cartTotal));

  }
  dataGridTotals.DataSource = list;

  dataGridTotals.DataBind();
```

I've tried using this after and before the gridview data is bound but it doesn't work:

```
dataGridTotals.Columns[0].HeaderText = "New Header for Column";
```

Has anyone got any other ideas?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# Gridview, " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Autogenerated columns do not populate the columns list. You will need to loop through the cell controls of the first row and manually change the text.

Comment: Check out Marc Gravell's way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036948/how-to-set-column-header-text-for-specific-column-in-datagridview-c-sharp

Comment: @John: Are prefixing/suffixing technologies always bad practise on SO? It makes a difference(and is also better searchable) when a question's title is `Group with LINQ` instead of `Group with SQL-Server`.

Comment: Again, that's what the tags are for. If you like, go ahead and work the tags into the title, like "Unable to change labels with the ASP.NET GridView". Note that the question has nothing to do with C#

Comment: @John: This was a general question independent to this question.

Comment: @Tim: questions like that should be asked on [meta]

Comment: @John: Thought that there was already a question on meta, but [now there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119400/best-practice-for-so-titles-according-to-prefixing-suffixing-technologies) ;-)

Comment: @Justin Satyt - can you point me in the right direction as to how to do this then?

Answer (score 2):

Autogenerated columns do not populate the columns list. You will need to loop through the cell controls of the first row and manually change the text.

Use this method for your grid's `RowDataBound` event. It will catch the header row and reassign text values. This code assumes you know the order in which your columns will be received. If not, you can read the text of each row and act accordingly...

```
private void gvMyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{                
    // Apply to header only.
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Column 1 Text";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Column 2 Text";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Column 3 Text";
    }
}
```

The above code assumes you know the order in which your columns will be received. If not, you can read the text of each row and act accordingly:

```
private void gvMyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{                
    // Apply to header only.
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (Cell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text == "FName")
            {
                cell.Text = "First Name";
            }
            else if (cell.Text == "LName")
            {
                cell.Text = "Last Name";
            }
            else if (cell.Text == "Etc")
            {
                cell.Text = "Et cetera";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this latter case, you would want to setup a dictionary of SQL field names and friendly English names to read so you don't have fifty `if` statements, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've actually solved the issue using the DisplayNameAttribute, I'll try this solution tomorrow though.

Comment: This will actually come in handy if you decide you need to make any of the columns invisible, change their width, etc.