# DATAGRID Columns header renaming

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I would like to make the header text of the columns in a data grid view to be exactly bounded to the caption of the data in the data table in my access database.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is the behavior you get by default when you bind datagridview to a datatable. How are you filling your datagrid?

Comment: i filling the data grid using a vb.net code and only by a code not by the wizard of the IDE of any tool only A CODE LIKE DATAGRIDVIEW1.MEMBER = "datatable

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036948/how-to-set-column-header-text-for-specific-column-in-datagridview-c-sharp